# How to stop focus() in custom js from scrolling to footer?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a js to create a "copy to clipboard" button, using the following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30905277/1544609):

```
function copy(selector){
  var $temp = $("<div>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.attr("contenteditable", true)
       .html($(selector).html()).select()
       .on("focus", function() { document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null); })
       .focus();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

I then load the script using the following:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_copy' );
function load_copy() {
    wp_enqueue_script('copyjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/copy.js', array('jquery') );
}
```

I then have a button setup to trigger this js onclick, to copy text from within a div element. The function works beautifully, except: because the js is loaded in the footer in WP, the `focus()` command causes the page to scroll to the bottom when the onclick event is triggered.

I've tried using `focus({preventScroll: true})` but then the function doesn't work, and I'm not savvy enough with js to figure out why.

Does anyone have a solution to stop the page from scrolling?

EDIT: adding the solution I'm now using, drawn from Veerji's answer below, with one change.

```
function copyToClipboard(selector){
        var $temp = jQuery("<div>");
        jQuery("body").append($temp);
        $temp.attr("contenteditable", true)
            .html(jQuery(selector).html()).css('position', 'fixed').select()
            .on("focus", function() { document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null); })
            .focus().css('position', 'static');
        document.execCommand("copy");
        $temp.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery `focus` by default scroll the page to the element. If we use `focus({preventScroll: true})` our copy function will not work as you mension.
So I have use some css hack. See the following jQuery code.

```
function copyToClipboard(selector, event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $temp = jQuery("<div>");
    jQuery("body").append($temp);
    $temp.attr("contenteditable", true)
      .html(jQuery(selector).html()).css('position', 'fixed').select()
      .on("focus", function() { document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null); })
      .focus().css('position', 'static');
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
}
```

This is working fine for me.

If you don't want to use this hack you can also use some pure javascript code. For example [this](https://codepen.io/shaikmaqsood/pen/XmydxJ)

Comment: When I try this, the browser throws up the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined` or `Uncaught TypeError: event is undefined`.

Edit: but if I remove that event it works perfectly!

Comment: To remove the js error add second arument as `event` in you function call like `onclick="copyToClipboard('#copy-jwf', event)"` on copy button. If without event it working no need to add event.